# Unable to change laptop power options

Tags: windows-7, power-management

OS: Windows 7 (32-bit)

Some time back, I had tried setting the default power plan as 'Balanced', by downloading and doing some changes in the registry.

Now I am unable to change the power options, its grayed out. Here's how it looks. For info, this is a personal laptop, and i have administrator rights.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The registry entries probably adjusted your local group policy settings.

So run gpedit.msc and check under the Computer Management/Policies/Administrative Templates/System/Power Management section. If something there is enabled, you should be able to set it to not configured.

Comment: Nothing seems to be configured there

Comment: Would you happen to have the registry entries you used?

Comment: Have to check, did it some months back..